# Pass JSON instead of Model from my controller to my Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view that inherit the following:

```
@model MvcApplication.Models.Application
```

But I need to know if it is possible to pass JSON objects to my view in the same way I am passing the model objects?
Since I have the following Controller:

```
public ActionResult ListPackages()
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
        //code goes here ....
        return Content(json, "application/json");
    }
}
```

which returns JSON using a API call, and then I am displaying the JSON on the view using JavaScript as follow:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: $('#geturl').data('url'),
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                $.each(result.data, function (key, val) {
                    var str = val.packageName;
                    $('<li/>', { text: str })
                        .appendTo($('#products'));
                });
            }
```

The problem with displaying the JSON using JavaScript is that it will make too difficult for me to work easily with the JSON objects, such as creating links based on the returned JSON or creating table that contain the JSON. So my question is: Is it possible to pass a JSON object instead of a Model object from my controller to my view?

Answer (score 4):

### Server- vs client-side confusion

You're talking two things here:

1. Creating a view: controller passes model to the view on the server side and it doesn't make much sense to do so using JSON, because an in-memory object is being passed to view engine.
2. Consuming JSON data on the client: what you're talking about here is client-server Ajax communication where you request data from the client and get JSON returned from the server. This has *arguably nothing to do with model data being passed to the view*

### Best solution using JSON

In order to easily consume JSON data (in your case it's an array of packages) on the client to generate resulting populated HTML is to use some sort of templating on the client side. jQuery used to have non-final templating plugin which is [now a separate project](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl). I've had great experience with it but there are other plugins as well. Use the one that you feel most comfortable with its syntax.

### Where to put those templates?

1. If you know the structure of your JSON objects passed from the server at the point of creating your view, you can put templates in the view itself and they'll just wait untill being used on the client.
2. If you don't know the structure of your JSON objects then you'll have to pass templates either along JSON object or as a separate request.

The first approach is the usual one, the second one is rarely used and is much more dynamic.

### Best solution not using JSON

If you don't like parsing JSON to HTML results (either manually or using templates), you can always make Ajax requests to your controller action, which would return a prepared HTML as a partial view instead of JSON result. This way, you could easily just put that HTML onto your page without any JSON data manipulation.

What do you gain here? Well suppose you have this functionality in your app:

1. You have a view that displays a paged list of packages.
2. When user first accesses the page first page of packages are being returned
3. Paging to next page is done via Ajax and the list is being replaced by returned data

If you'd create a partial view for your subsequent Ajax request, you can use the same partial view in your main view to display the first page of packages. This will ensure that you only have to change one partial view and display would change on inital page load as well as subsequent package paging.

If you used view + JSON + templating that means that you have to maintain **two** presentations of package list: the one being used in the view for the first page and the template that displays subsequent paging.

### Which one then?

All things being equal it makes the second solution better. But the choice of course depends on your case (of things not being equal) and you should be able to determine which one is best in your scenario.

Comment: thank a lot for your useful reply. But in my case i have to deal with JSON heavily, since i am integrating with a JSON API provided by external system ,, so i am calling the JSON API using a URL and then they send me JSON .. so i do not have any other option but to deal with JSON ...

Comment: @johnG: Ok in that case it's the easiest thing to use templates then. templating engines will give you the possibility to just give them your template and your JSON object and they'll *spit out* resulting HTML. As simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. A view must be strongly typed to a model. So one solution would be to deserialize this JSON into a model object before passing it to the view:

```
public ActionResult ListPackages()
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
        //code goes here ....

        var model = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<MyViewModel>(json);
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

where `MyViewModel` would of course reflect the JSON structure that you are working with.

Comment: thanks for your reply, and should the ViewModel object have properties representing each of the JSON values?

Comment: this approach seems valid to me ,, but will it cause performance or security drawbacks ? .